# MySQL three table chained left join, filtering by last table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find an effective way to filter out result set produced by chained three tables left join, where second table join would take into account third table's properties.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e319e/2/0

A simplified example would be a join between three tables: Post, Comment and Author. Posts can have 0..N comments that are written by an Author. I'd like to get a list of all Posts + active Comments written only by active Authors.

Considering the following data:

**Post:**

```
| id |       title |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |  First post |
|  2 | Second post |
|  3 |  Third post |
|  4 |  Forth post |
```

**Author**:

```
| id |                  title | is_active |
|----|------------------------|-----------|
|  1 |           First author |         1 |
|  2 |          Second author |         1 |
|  3 |           Third author |         1 |
|  4 | Fourth inactive author |         0 |
|  5 |  Fifth inactive author |         0 |
```

**Comment**:

```
| id | post_id | author_id |                  title | is_active |
|----|---------|-----------|------------------------|-----------|
|  1 |       1 |         1 |          First comment |         1 |
|  2 |       2 |         1 |         Second comment |         1 |
|  3 |       1 |         2 |          Third comment |         1 |
|  4 |       2 |         4 |         Fourth comment |         1 |
|  5 |       2 |         5 | Fifth inactive comment |         0 |
|  6 |       2 |         3 | Sixth inactive comment |         0 |
|  7 |       4 |         4 |        Seventh comment |         1 |
```

Now executing simple filtering query:

```
SELECT
  p.id post_id, p.title post_title,
  c.id as comment_id, c.title comment, c.is_active active_comment,
  a.id author_id, a.title author, a.is_active active_author
FROM Post p
LEFT JOIN Comment c ON c.post_id = p.id AND c.is_active = 1
LEFT JOIN Author a ON a.id = c.author_id AND a.is_active = 1
ORDER BY p.id;
```

brings us the following result set:

```
| id |       title |     id |           title | is_active |     id |         title | is_active |
|----|-------------|--------|-----------------|-----------|--------|---------------|-----------|
|  1 |  First post |      1 |   First comment |         1 |      1 |  First author |         1 |
|  1 |  First post |      3 |   Third comment |         1 |      2 | Second author |         1 |
|  2 | Second post |      2 |  Second comment |         1 |      1 |  First author |         1 |
|  2 | Second post |      4 |  Fourth comment |         1 | (null) |        (null) |    (null) |
|  3 |  Third post | (null) |          (null) |    (null) | (null) |        (null) |    (null) |
|  4 |  Forth post |      7 | Seventh comment |         1 | (null) |        (null) |    (null) |
```

that has two comments that should be omitted - "Forth comment" and "Seventh comment" that have been written by inactive authors.

The only way I see that would work is to add JOIN condition for Comment

```
AND c.id IN (SELECT id FROM Author WHERE is_active = 1)
```

that produces a correct result set, but I guess is not very optimal. However I can't find any other working solution. Is there some way to optimize it somehow? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a problem with your data integrity.  You have *active* comments written by *inactive* authors?  When the author is inactivated, shouldn't the comment be inactivated as well?  Note: you still have a good question; I just think you might want a fix outside just this query.

Comment: Why do you want the "Third Post", which has nothing active?

Comment: Gordon, as I wrote, it's a simplified example - a real scenario is a bit different. However even in this scenario I'd say active comment with inactive author could make sense - say author gets temporary suspended for a week, but we don't want to deactivate his comments immediately. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: Tim, because primarily a list of all Posts is needed + comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this `from` clause:

```
FROM Post p LEFT JOIN
     (Comment c JOIN
      Author a
      ON a.id = c.author_id AND a.is_active = 1 and c.is_active = 1
     )
     ON c.post_id = p.id
```

As I mention in the comment, though, you might want to inactivate comments by inactive authors.  That would involve a trigger or stored procedure.

Oh, and you were polite enough to put up a SQL Fiddle, so [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e319e/6) it is working.

Comment: @KlausK .  .  . I would expect this query to have the same execution time as your query (the two versions are doing basically the same joins).  Your question was about functionality not performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit "Third post" too (only by active Authors),  you can try this:

```
 SELECT 
  p.id post_id, p.title post_title,
  c.id as comment_id, c.title comment, c.is_active active_comment,
  a.id author_id, a.title author, a.is_active active_author
 FROM Post p
 LEFT JOIN Comment c ON c.post_id = p.id 
 LEFT JOIN Author a ON a.id = c.author_id
 WHERE c.is_active = 1 AND a.is_active = 1
 ORDER BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do too:

```
select a.title, p.title, c.title 
from author a 
left join comment c on a.id = c.author_id
left join post p on c.post_id = p.id
where a.id in (select id from author where is_active = 1) 
and c.is_active = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e319e/1